# how to get excel sheet name using index c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2013, .net-3.5

I am trying to import multiple excel `workbook` and bind it to `datagridview`
as shown below my problem is I want to get sheet name using index to make 
this method fixable I am getting error that says

I tried zero index I am get error too Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))

**Note** that excel workbook may has one or more sheets

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
>   Message=Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B
>   (DISP_E_BADINDEX))   Source=Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
>   ErrorCode=-2147352565   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets.get_Item(Object Index)
>          at BlackList.F0100.ImportExcel(String FilePath) in d:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\BlackList\BlackList\F0100.cs:line 88
>          at BlackList.F0100.GetFilesList() in d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BlackList\BlackList\F0100.cs:line 71
>          at BlackList.F0100.B_Import_Data_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\BlackList\BlackList\F0100.cs:line 125
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(Int32
>   dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32
>   reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          at BlackList.Program.Main() in d:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\BlackList\BlackList\Program.cs:line 18
>          at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
>          at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()   InnerException:

```
    public void ImportExcel(string FilePath)
    {
        string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FilePath + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";";
        string cmdtxt = @"select * from [Sheet222$]";

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
        excelApp.Visible = true;

        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(FilePath,
                0, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        Excel.Sheets excelSheets = excelWorkbook.Worksheets;

        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(0);

        MessageBox.Show(excelWorksheet.Name, "test msg");

        excelWorkbook.Close(0);

        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr))
        {
            conn.Open();

            OleDbDataAdapter DA = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmdtxt, conn);
            DA.Fill(dt);
            DGV_Data.DataSource = dt;

            conn.Close();
        }

        //Calculate record counts
        L_Rows_Count.Text = "count: " + (DGV_Data.Rows.Count - 1).ToString("n0");

    }
```

Comment: Debug your code... the exception seems to suggest that there is no sheet at index 1 (the index collection is [zero-based](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/05c92891-b839-45c8-80df-eb35e2d68258/how-to-get-the-sheet-name-from-an-excel-file-in-cnet?forum=csharpgeneral)). Also, closing the workbook and subequently using a sheet from the closed workbook (as in `MessageBox.Show`) will fail. The property you want is the `Name` property of the `Worksheet` object.

Comment: @dlatikay i forget to mention that I tried zero index I am get error too `Invalid index. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8002000B (DISP_E_BADINDEX))`... post Updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think,

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)excelSheets.get_Item(1);
            string name = excelWorksheet.Name;//Sheet Name
```